# Where is the importHref function?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm having such a hard time trying to use the [Polymer.importHref](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/#function-Polymer.importHref) function...

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're only importing `polymer-element.html`, make sure to also import `import-href.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="polymer/lib/utils/import-href.html">
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YQKrvx?editors=1012)